# QTableview properties

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, resizable

I need help with customizing a `QTableView`, I have defined a `QTableView` as this example show, which I found on the internet:

```
model = new QStandardItemModel(2,3,this); //2 Rows and 3 Columns
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("ID")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Name")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Description")));
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

1. How can I define a size for each column separately i.e using percentages:
   I would get first column 10% of the width second 50%, third 40%.
2. When I run the program and double click on a row in the `QTableView`, I can change the value of the cell clicked on , although I have defined a `QTableView` `onDoubleclick` method , I mean its like when you click on rename a file it highlights the text so you can modify, how can I disable that?
3. How to make the columns resizable, meaning can be resized by dragging their columns edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Use `setColumnWidth()` method after `setModel()`. For example:

```
//...
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
double  ii = ui->tableView->columnWidth(0);

ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(1,0.4*ii);    
ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(2,0.5*ii);
```

Third: To do this remove

```
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

from your code.

Comment: the strech worked thanks , but ui->tableView->columnWidth(0); returns 0

Comment: @saeedhardan because you use it before setModel, your tableView has no anything, that's why you get 0. See my edit please, I wrote solution.

Comment: and for 2 i just unchecked the doubleclick in the edittriggers , THANKS A LOT